# Intuition behind irrationality of $\pi$

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi, continued-fractions

Would the existence of arbitrarily large terms in the continued fraction expansion of $\pi$ imply its irrationality?

Edit: I completely changed the question to remove speculation on my part.

Comment: Do you mean the numbers that appear in the expansion, or the fact that the expansion is infinite?

Comment: ...do you _know_ that there are arbitrarily large terms in the continued fraction expansion of $\pi$?

Comment: I don't know that there are arbitrarily large terms in the continued fraction expansion of $\pi$.

Comment: Given that AFAIK it's not actually known that there are arbitrarily large terms, I don't think you can really use the word 'because' there since the supposed cause isn't even known for certain but $\pi$'s irrationality is.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I'm not sure if it addresses the question. To a large extent, that's because the question statement itself has issues. However, if the asker found my reformulation in terms of periodicity useful, let me know and I'll restore the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of infinitely many terms in the simple continued fraction is enough to imply a number is irrational, if if they're not unbounded.  But they can be unbounded only if there are infinitely many.

To see that a number must be irrational if it continued fraction expansion has infinitely many terms, consider this:
\begin{align}
& \frac{175}{81} = 2 + \cfrac{13}{81} & & \text{The numerator 13 is smaller than the numerator 175.} \\[10pt]
= {} & 2 + \frac 1 {\left( \dfrac{81}{13} \right)} = 2 + \cfrac 1 {6+ \cfrac 3 {13}} & & \text{The numerator 3 is smaller than the numerator 81.} \\[10pt]
= {} & 2 + \cfrac 1 {6 + \cfrac 1 {\left( \cfrac {13} 3 \right)} } = 2 + \cfrac 1 {6 + \cfrac 1 {4 + \cfrac 1 3}} & & \text{The numerator 1 is smaller than the numerator 13.}
\end{align}
**You cannot keep getting smaller positive integers forever.** Therefore the simple continued fraction expansion of a rational number terminates.

But any proof that the simple continued fraction expansion of $\pi$ does not terminate must require some work.

Comment: The argument seems a bit confused. What is the strictly decreasing sequence of integers in question? I see $175>13$, $81>3$, $13>1$ but I don't know if you are going for $(175,13,1)$ or $(175,81,13)$ or $(13,3,1)$ or something else.

Comment: Because if $a>b$ then the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$ is less than $b$, and _a fortiori_ is less than $a$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MarioCarneiro : $$(175,81) \mapsto (13,81) \mapsto (13,3) \mapsto (1,3)$$  At each step the larger of the two numbers is replaced by a number that is smaller than the smaller of the two numbers. $\qquad$

Comment: You could simplify that to $81>13>3>1$ if you just take the denominators on the right in each step. (Oh wait, I guess you are trying to capture the whole state with those pairs...) Also, [the Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is relevant.